# Using Map on Function if name of df lists match

Tags: r, dictionary, if-statement, spatial

I have given a

a namend vector col:

```
 col <- c(id = "CLUSTER", x = "LONGNUM", y = "LATNUM", n = "Severely.stunted.child.under.5.years..Total", pos = "Severely.stunted.child.under.5.years.Yes")
```

#a List of Dataframes with the the Elements of col as Columns and namend after a specific study area. (see deput below) The List Results contains 19 different files (different years)

a list of shapefiles of with 6 Elements (corresponding countries):

```
study_area <- c("Ethiopia", "Liberia", "Malawi", "Rwanda", "Uganda", "Zimbabwe")
Countries <- lapply(study_area, function(x){gisco_get_countries(country=  x, resolution = 60 )})
Countries <- lapply(Countries, function(x) {as_Spatial(x, cast = TRUE, IDs = c("CNTR_NAME", "ISO§_CODE", "CNRT_ID", "NAME_ENGL", "FID"))})
names(Countries) <- study_area
```

I would like to preform the function from the prevR Library :

```
s.prevR(Results[[1]], col, Countries[[1]])
```

But actually for every element in the lists where the names fit:

I tried something like: `Map(function(x, y) { as.prevR(x, col, y)}, Results, Countries)`

But there it does (obviously) not match by names of x and y

```
dput( dput(Results[[1]][1:5,1:24])
structure(list(CLUSTER = c("", "1", "10", "100", "101"), Severely.stunted.child.under.5.years.No = c(3438, 
8, 7, 9, 6), Severely.stunted.child.under.5.years.Yes = c(1047, 
4, NA, 7, 1), Severely.stunted.child.under.5.years..Total = c(4485, 
12, 7, 16, 7), Stunted.child.under.5.years.No = c(2531, 2, 7, 
7, 5), Stunted.child.under.5.years.Yes = c(1954, 10, NA, 9, 2
), Stunted.child.under.5.years..Total = c(4485, 12, 7, 16, 7), 
    Severely.wasted.child.under.5.years.No = c(4295, 11, 7, 16, 
    7), Severely.wasted.child.under.5.years.Yes = c(190, 1, NA, 
    NA, NA), Severely.wasted.child.under.5.years..Total = c(4485, 
    12, 7, 16, 7), Wasted.child.under.5.years.No = c(3957, 10, 
    7, 16, 6), Wasted.child.under.5.years.Yes = c(528, 2, NA, 
    NA, 1), Wasted.child.under.5.years..Total = c(4485, 12, 7, 
    16, 7), Severely.underweight.child.under.5.years.No = c(4028, 
    10, 7, 12, 7), Severely.underweight.child.under.5.years.Yes = c(457, 
    2, NA, 4, NA), Severely.underweight.child.under.5.years..Total = c(4485, 
    12, 7, 16, 7), Underweight.child.under.5.years.No = c(3185, 
    7, 7, 12, 5), Underweight.child.under.5.years.Yes = c(1300, 
    5, NA, 4, 2), Underweight.child.under.5.years..Total = c(4485, 
    12, 7, 16, 7), LATNUM = c(NA, 10.889096, 5.323272, 8.830199, 
    10.806748), LONGNUM = c(NA, 37.269565, 39.556812, 40.72964, 
    39.7703), SurveyId = c("ET2005DHS", "ET2005DHS", "ET2005DHS", 
    "ET2005DHS", "ET2005DHS"), DHSC = c("ET", "ET", "ET", "ET", 
    "ET"), Country = c("Ethiopia", "Ethiopia", "Ethiopia", "Ethiopia", 
    "Ethiopia")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

and Countries

```
dput(Countries[[1]])
new("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", data = structure(list(CNTR_NAME = "Federal Democratic Republic of Ethiopia", 
    ISO3_CODE = "ETH", CNTR_ID = "ET", NAME_ENGL = "Ethiopia", 
    FID = "ET"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), polygons = list(
    new("Polygons", Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(39.6420582930584, 
    8.63562315843106), area = 93.13026982, hole = FALSE, ringDir = 1L, 
        coords = structure(c(41.6307, 42.4043, 41.816, 41.8348, 
        42.9681, 42.7628, 42.9804, 43.9589, 45.6126, 46.9411, 
        47.8524, 45.6126, 45.4747, 45.2923, 44.9162, 43.4741, 
        42.8138, 41.9101, 41.2328, 40.708, 39.9305, 39.5667, 
        38.9731, 38.1026, 36.9621, 35.9477, 35.8294, 35.3235, 
        35.0325, 34.9588, 34.5428, 33.7557, 33.0448, 33.2485, 
        33.8204, 34.0937, 34.1132, 34.4181, 34.8021, 35.2153, 
        35.6227, 36.1342, 36.5603, 37.2972, 37.5268, 37.9201, 
        38.5391, 39.0217, 40.0851, 40.8941, 41.6307, 13.3913, 
        12.4686, 11.6292, 11.0448, 10.9974, 10.7159, 10.0644, 
        9.0545, 8.4674, 8.0224, 7.9151, 5.5657, 5.4241, 5.2367, 
        4.9368, 4.7993, 4.301, 3.9823, 3.9616, 4.2326, 3.8858, 
        3.5224, 3.5158, 3.6459, 4.3833, 4.62, 5.2367, 5.413, 
        5.8494, 6.4537, 6.7418, 7.6074, 7.899, 8.381, 8.4168, 
        8.6026, 9.4986, 10.6735, 10.8052, 11.9187, 12.5064, 12.8315, 
        14.2577, 14.3876, 14.2588, 14.8128, 14.4413, 14.5899, 
        14.5456, 14.0891, 13.3913), dim = c(51L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, 
        labpt = c(39.6420582930584, 8.63562315843106), ID = "1", 
        area = 93.13026982)), plotOrder = 1L, bbox = structure(c(33.0448, 
3.5158, 47.8524, 14.8128), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(c("x", 
"y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

Comment: You may do `nmsCommon <- intersect(names(Results), names(Countries)); Map(function(x, y) { as.prevR(x, col, y)}, Results[nmsCommon], Countries[nmsCommon])`

Comment: Actually: my Results have 19 dfs (repeating the names of y) and my y as 6 shapes. But I would like to run the code on all 19 dfs, and not just 6 times. sorry for that bad discription of mine. My output should contain 19 Spatial polygons

Comment: Do you have names repeated in the Countries? Also, assuming you have names of Results are all in COuntries, `Map(function(x, y) { as.prevR(x, col, y)}, Results, Countries[names(Results)])`

Comment: No, but in the Results file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Countries` names are all in the `Results` names and if 'Results' have duplicates for names, then we can make the `Countries` to have the same length by replicating based on the names of the 'Results'

```
Map(function(x, y) { as.prevR(x, col, y)}, Results, Countries[names(Results)])
```